# c++ STL what shall I return a query for List/Set?

Tags: stl

Component A own a set containing pointers, I plan to design a API to return the set.
Currently other component only read the content of set, no intention to change anything, which shall I return from the API.

Options are:
1. Return a copy of the set
2. Return an reference of the set
3. Return a pair of the iterator of set. `std:pair<ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end>`

Concern is:
1. Maybe some overhead to copy. 
2. This expose the internal set, it can not stop other components to change it.
3. If component A modify the set, will it invalid the iterator?

Comment: What do users of the API need? Should they even know it's a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being let's assume you're sure about this: `ComponentA` owns
a set of pointers, `std::set<Thing *>`, and you want it to have a method to return that set, but
so that the receiving client code cannot modify it. You're unsure whether to:

1. Return a copy of the set.
2. Return a reference to the set.
3. Return the [`begin()`, `end()`) range of the set.

Don't do any of those. Each one has the flaw that you have identified yourself,
and **3** has the additional flaw that it doesn't return *the set*. The client
code receiving the iterator range won't know that it delimits a *set* and
won't be able to take advantage of the defining properties of a *set*.

Instead, return a `const` reference to the set from a `const` method:

```
struct ComponentA
{
    ...
    ...
    std:set<Thing *> const & get_set_of_things() const {
        return things;
    }
private:
    std::set<Thing *> things
    ...
};
```

This removes the drawback of **2** - client code can't modify the set through
a `const` reference - and it doesn't have any of the other snags.

I hope that answers your question, *but I'm afraid it's not the end of your design problems*.

Client code can't modify `things` through the
`std:set<Thing *> const &` returned by `get_set_of_things()`. But
the things that I can't modify are the members of that set, which are merely 
*pointers* to `Thing`. I certainly don't care what those pointers are - memory addresses like
`0x1a04c20` - and I have no interest in modifying *them*. But nothing
is stopping me from modifying any of the `Things` that those pointers
point to, e.g.

```
ComponentA ca;
...
auto const & things = ca.get_set_of_things;
Thing * pthing = *things.begin();
thing->modify();
...
```

This modifies one of the `Things` controlled by `ca` - which is what you
want to prevent.

However you return the set from a `ComponentA` object, you can't prevent the client from modifying
the `Things` controlled by the object as long as you are giving them `Thing *`-pointers.

Well you could block this threat by changing `things` to a set of `const`
pointers:

```
struct ComponentA
{
    ...
    ...
    std:set<Thing const *> const & get_set_of_things() const {
        return things;
    }
private:
    std::set<Thing const *> things
    ...
};
```

But the fallout of that change is that now `ComponentA` *itself* can't
modify any of the `Things` controlled by `things`. Can you live with that?

And this is just the first of several loud design alarms that are triggered
by the information that your `ComponentA` controls a *set of pointers*.
I suggest you draft your class definition and put it up for
comment on SO's sister-site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).
It's beyond the scope of SO to explore all the likely pitfalls, especially
in the absence of any code.

Comment: Mike: You are perfectly right. Return a const reference will be the best choice for it. And I can live with the set hold Thing* pointer currently.